# Proper way of reporting performance data for C# application in a Container (Docker)

Tags: c#, .net, performance, docker, performancecounter

Back in the old VM days, we used to create Performance Counters for reporting what's going on inside a Windows application, and used `perfmon` or related tools to monitor, archive and the analyse such data.

Now that Containers are the way to go, there are a lot of ambiguities for what's right to do. I'm writing a new performance-critical application intended to be deployed as a Docker image, and need to report some measures. And I happen to have many questions about what to do:

- Is performance counters the way to go?
- If not, what is?
- Is there adequate tooling to support gathering performance counters from containers?
- Is that meaningful for many containers running on a host?
- If I run many (like 100) instances of a docker image, how to make sense of the performance data?
- Can I ask some tools to go gather all of the performance counters from all instances of the images, and give me some kind of aggregate (sum/avg/...)?

So, in summary, what is the proper way of reporting performance measures (say how many times the execution passed a certain point in code) in C# / .NET applications intended for the scale-out deployment on the Docker containers?

Comment: Where your containers are deployed? In cloud or on premise? For instance AWS ECS has many metrics to monitor container performance and health.

Comment: My plan is deployment on Windows Server 2016 containers, on-premises.